# Top 5 reasons for using ASP.NET MVC 2 rather than ASP.NET MVC 1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I've been using ASP.NET MVC 1 for a while now, and am keen to take advantage of the improvements in MVC 2. Things like validation seem greatly improved, and strongly-typed HTML helper methods look great.

So, for those of you who have **real-world practical experience** of using ASP.NET MVC 1 and are now using MVC 2, what are your top 5 reasons for using MVC 2?

Comment: Voted down because of the 180 edit.  Edits like this aren't helpful and you should have opened a separate question.  This is also inconsiderate to answerers, you basically wasted tvanfosson's time.

Comment: @jfar: My initial question wasn't 100% clear, tvanfosson edited it for clarity but actually in the opposite direction in which I intended. So I rolled back that edit, and clarified my question. No offence indended.

Comment: Note that MVC 3 is now available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. TemplatedHelpers EditorFor, DisplayFor
2. ViewPage changes with ModelMetadata and ViewData.TemplateInfo as properties accessibile in the View.
3. MVC Areas + MVCContrib Portable Areas
4. ModelBinding changes result in more secure MVC apps for free.
5. DataAnnotationsModelBinder is a huge timesaver for validating CRUD forms.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**: The question underwent a complete 180 (an instance of the [Obama problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33997/please-ditch-the-five-minute-window-on-comment-editing)) after my answer was written.   Upgrading to the 2.0 release of a product seems like a no-brainer to me.  The other question was actually more interesting.

I wouldn't unless your app is nearly complete and you don't anticipate new development soon.  The number of breaking changes between MVC1 and MVC2 is pretty minimal and you can still use the MVC1 constructs while incorporating new MVC2 constructs in new development.  I'm in the process of updating a reasonably large app (50K+ lines of code) from MVC1 to MVC2, and even accounting for the dumb things I did (like not using view-specific models and directly interacting with the ValueProvider) when writing the app as I was learning MVC1, it took me only a few days to make the switch.

So here is my list:

1. I'm releasing in the next week or so.
2. The app is complete and I'm not doing any more development.

Comment: It seems that you have answered the question "top reasons NOT to use MVC2" that is quite opposite to what is asked

Comment: @iPhone - except that he edited the question and completely changed it.   Look at the edit history; complete reversal.

Comment: No offence intended - I've commented my quesiton accordingly.

Comment: @Richard - It is annoying to have a question change signficantly enough to make you look like an idiot. Next time you might want to leave a comment for anyone whose answer no longer makes sense after an edit to give them a chance to update it and let people know that it's not the answer's fault (necessarily).

Comment: I think the risk of you looking like an idiot here is quite theoretical. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Areas
2. New HTML helpers
3. *Much* better Model support (`Html.TextBoxFor<T>()`)
4. 2 > 1
5. Easy conversion